# What's the difference between HandDraggable and GestureAction scripts in the Holotoolkit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, hololens-emulator

These two scripts, HandDraggable.cs and GestureAction.cs, seem to do very similar things.  The MR Academy implements the GestureAction script.  What is the difference between these 2 scripts and when would you use one or the other?

Comment: Do you have code samples of these scripts? Hard to determine the difference if we don't have the code.

Comment: @remy_rm The scripts are part of the Holotoolkit.  If you aren't familiar with the scripts and haven't used them in practice I think it would be hard to compare/contrast them and when you would use one over the other.

Comment: Glancing over the 2 scripts, `HandDraggable.cs` is a ready-made component whose task is solely for translation an object in the 3D space. Whereas `GestureAction.cs` is a component created for the purposes of a tutorial and is not actually a part of the HoloToolkit package. It defines a custom action - which could be rotation, scale, translation, etc. They are similar because `GestureAction.cs` uses the using `HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule` namespace, of which `HandDraggable.cs` is a member, and the tasks they accomplish are both started with a manipulation event.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the reply.  Let me validate this today and let you know so you can post an answer and get the bounty.

Comment: @Enfyve Please turn your comment into an answer and I'll mark it correct and give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HandDraggable.cs` is a ready-made component whose task is solely for translation an object in the 3D space.

`GestureAction.cs` is a component created for the purposes of a tutorial and is not actually a part of the HoloToolkit package.

It defines a custom action - which could be rotation, scale, translation, etc. They are similar because `GestureAction.cs` uses the using `HoloToolkit.Unity.InputModule` namespace, of which `HandDraggable.cs` is a member, and the tasks they accomplish are both started with a manipulation event.